# Assign Javascript array into PHP array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I'm posting Javascript array `cellValues` using following code:

```
$.post('test.php', {cellvalues: celValues});
```

test.php:

```
<?php
$i=0;
$arr= array();
foreach($_POST['celValues'] as $val)
{
    $arr[i]=$val;
    echo $arr[i];
    $i++; 
}
```

The PHP code is not working. So how can I assign the JS array into a PHP array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$arr = $_POST['cellvalues'];
```

And in the Javascript:

```
$.post('test.php', {cellvalues: celValues.serialize()});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$_POST['celValues']
```

should be

```
$_POST['cellvalues']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post('test.php', {cellvalues: celValues.serialize()});
```

As a side-note, is the variable `celValues` meant to be `cellValues`?

Answer (score 1):

try like this. 'cellvalues' instead of cellvalues

```
$.post('test.php', {'cellvalues': celValues.serialize()});
```